# com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException error in android

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying out a simple coding to build an app with api using volley but get the error jsonexception of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {>
    Button btn_Submit;
    EditText et_dataInput;
    ListView lv_files;

    String file_name;
    String file_category;
    String file_keyword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_Submit = findViewById(R.id.btn_Submit);
        et_dataInput = findViewById(R.id.et_dataInput);
        lv_files = findViewById(R.id.lv_files);

        btn_Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
//keyword is cv
                String url = "http://ws2.samdel.net/mongodb_api.php?s=" + et_dataInput.getText().toString();

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("files");

                            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);

                                file_name = jo.getString("files_name");
                                file_category = jo.getString("files_category");
                                file_keyword = jo.getString("files_keyword");

                                final HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                                data.put("files_name", ""+file_name);
                                data.put("files_category", ""+file_category);
                                data.put("files_keyword", ""+file_keyword);

                                list.add(data);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                                MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

                        lv_files.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.i("My error", "Error Occurred" + error);
                    }
                });
              //Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I added a new line trying to populate the list but it seems that JSONArray doesn't produce any result. Did i miss something?

I got this error

`org.json.JSONException: Value {"data":[{"_id":{"$oid":"637d0868f79eb6bab4957151"},"files_name":"CV_Intern_Adella","files_category":"intern student","files_keyword":"cv, intern, job, experience, name, matric, university"}],"status":"OK"} at files of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Does anyone know what seems to be the problem and how can i fix it? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn_Submit;
    EditText et_dataInput;
    ListView lv_files;

    String file_name;
    String file_category;
    String files_keyword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_Submit = findViewById(R.id.btn_Submit);
        et_dataInput = findViewById(R.id.et_dataInput);
        lv_files = findViewById(R.id.lv_files);

        btn_Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
                String url = "http://ws2.samdel.net/mongodb_api.php";

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("files");

                        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                            file_name = jo.getString("<YOUR KEY NAME for file_name>");
                            file_category = jo.getString("<YOUR KEY NAME for file_category>");
                            files_keyword = jo.getString("<YOUR KEY NAME for file_keyword>");

                            final HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            data.put("<YOUR KEY NAME for file_name>", ""+file_name);
                            data.put("<YOUR KEY NAME for file_category>", ""+file_category);
                            data.put("<YOUR KEY NAME for file_keyword>", ""+files_keyword);

                            list.add(data);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //you can add your array to list view in here
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(admin.this,list,R.layout.feedback_list,
                    new String[]{"YOUR_KEY_NAME"},
                    new int[]{R.id.YOUR_TEXTVIEW_ID_IN_LISTVIEW});
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("My error", "" + error);
                }
            });

//              Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: error says Cannot resolve constructor 'JSONObject(org.json.JSONArray)'

Comment: you need to add these imports **import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;**

Comment: there's still an error. i'll edit the post and put in the full code for you.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, is data.put("files_name", ""+file_name); would be right? and can you explain a bit on ""+file_name. i don't quite understand about the empty string. thank you again

Comment: It helps convert your array value to string. same as **toString** method

Comment: Hello, i edited my post can you take a look at it. I tried to populate the listview with the array but there are no results made and the error files of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray is back